# Problem with Spring Boot Configuration Server

Tags: spring-boot

i'm getting application.properties file from github by using this url(https://github.com/Asrit1247/Configuration). My problem is i need to check properties file loaded or not. when ever i make request with http://localhost:1111/application.properties this url i got 404 error(requested page is not there).I need to find wether this configuration server is successfully loads properties file from gihub or not.

I got some exceptions when i run my spring boot application class..like

```
2018-10-08 23:34:18.005  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}- {profiles}.properties],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.properties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean)throws java.io.IOException
2018-10-08 23:34:18.011  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}-{profiles}.yml || /{name}-{profiles}.yaml],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController. yaml(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception  
2018-10-08 23:34:18.045  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}/{profiles:.* [^-].*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController .defaultLabel(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-10-08 23:34:18.049  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "enter code here{[/{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController. labelled(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-10-08 23:34:18.051  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}- {profiles}.yml || /{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yaml],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController .labelledYaml(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-10-08 23:34:18.054  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{name}- {profiles}.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController .jsonProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-10-08 23:34:18.059  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}- {profiles}.properties],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController  .labelledProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String ,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-10-08 23:34:18.063  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/{label}/{name}- {profiles}.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController .labelledJsonProperties(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String, boolean) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-10-08 23:34:18.077  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped " {[/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet- stream]}" onto public synchronized byte[] org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.binary (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http .HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
2018-10-08 23:34:18.119  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped " {[/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.retrieve (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http .HttpServletRequest,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
2018-10-08 23:34:18.121  INFO 14960 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped " {[/{name}/{profile}/**],methods=[GET],params=[useDefaultLabel]}" onto public java.lang.String  org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController .retrieve(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http .HttpServletRequest,boolean) throws java.io.IOException
```

Try to verify why these exceptions are came and how to solve these errors...please help me out with this problem

### Below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/ XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sathya</groupId>
<artifactId>sathyatel-config-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sathyatel-config-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<!--  ACTUATOR -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Below is my application.properties file

```
server.port=1111
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=
https://github.com/Asrit1247/Configuration
```

#### SathyatelConfigServerApplication.java

```
package com.sathya.sathyatelconfigserver;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class SathyatelConfigServerApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(SathyatelConfigServerApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to do. I am totally confused.

Comment: actually what i'm doing is i will make my boot application as Cloud Configuration Server.Using this Server i'll get my properties file from github repository.For that i need to check wether this Configuration Server is working or not.After running this server i'll make a request like http://localhost:1111/application.properties, this url show all properties that are available in application.properties in github repository.when i make request it shows httpstatus:404,i dont no what is the problem with my program..if u nderstood help me out.

Comment: @AyyappaBheemireddy Can you please edit your question with what you are trying to do instead of having it as a comment? I found your question to be confusing until I read the comments. You also should check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future reference :)

Comment: move your explanation to question and looks like you already got correct answer.

Comment: definitely i'll change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log messages you shared are not "exceptions" but rather a list of autoconfigured endpoints that have a handler method signature that throws an exception.  These endpoints are defined [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/abbd14fd01901dc62d61ce6f0fabb54b9b4b85a5/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/EnvironmentController.java). Also note the `INFO` log level of those messages.

Additionally, when testing config server by making a `GET` call, you'll need to pass the profile name.  Example: http://localhost:1111/application-default.properties or http://localhost:1111/application/default

**[Spring Cloud Config Documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html)**

Comment: tq so much i got solution